# Por que mi navegador no me descarga ni me pide descargar mi archivo generado con DOMPDF Laravel?

Tags: laravel, dompdf, internet-explorer

Buenas gente tengo el problema que cuando quiero que me pida descargar el archivo con el metodo download de PDF no me lo descarga, pero si le doy con el metodo save si lo guarda en la carpeta publica. este es mi codigo:

```
public function imprimir($id)
    {
      $aporte = Aporte::Where('id','=',$id)->get();
      $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
      $pdf = PDF::loadView('Reportes.recibo', compact('aporte'));
      return $pdf->download('factura.pdf');
    }
```

PD. intente con Google chrome, mozilla y safari.

Comment: Qué tipo de método es la ruta que está adjunta con ese método imprimir()? Debe ser `GET` para que funcione.

Comment: de hecho no tengo ruta, uso livewire y pues no he utilizado. solo utilizo esto: <button wire:click="imprimir({{$ap->id}})" class="btn btn-outline-success mx-2">Imp.